# with data.table, optimised match within range then do function on selected data

Tags: r, data.table, matching

Say I have a data.tables of a sequence of measurements like so:

```
raw = rbind(
  data.table(id = "first", seq = 1:100, val1 = runif(100), val2 = runif(100)),
  data.table(id = "second", seq = 1:100, val1 = runif(100), val2 = runif(100))
  )
```

with a companion data.table which highlights parts of the sequence of interest.

```
timings = data.table(id = c("first", "first", "second"),
                    start = c(5, 50, 9),
                    end = c(10, 60, 19))
```

What's the data.table way of searching though each id, finding the seq values which are between the start and end values. then calculate the associated means for val1 and val2?

Such that my result table would look like:

```
       id start end mean_val1  mean_val2
1:  first     5  10 0.2645239 0.02060684
2:  first    50  60 0.6795851 0.90318952
3: second     9  19 0.3591886 0.26836045
```

While I know how to accomplish something like this with some loops, that's not very R. Plus my tables are actually rather large.

What would be a data.table approach?

Comment: There are "range" functions in data.table docs. Have you done any searching with that word?

Comment: +This wasn't the first hit for the search I did `[r] data.table select row range` but it appears to be good one.